# how to reach model from different view controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm not new to OOP but i'm very new to objective c and i've been having trouble with reaching model from two different view controllers, one to set it the other to get the data. Here's my model:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ModelUnit : NSObject{
    NSString * nickname;
    int total;
}

- (void)setTotal:(int)newTotal;
- (void)setName:(NSString *)nick;
- (NSString *)getName;

@end

#import "ModelUnit.h"

@implementation ModelUnit

- (void)setTotal:(int)newTotal{
    total = newTotal;
}

- (void)setName:(NSString *)nick{
    nickname = nick;
}

- (NSString *)getName{
    return nickname;
}


@end
```

Here's how i try to set nickname in the initial viewcontroller:

```
   //.h
  @interface introViewController : UIViewController{

    ModelUnit * modl;
}

-(ModelUnit *) modl;
-(IBAction)nickEntered:(UITextField *)sender;

@end

//.m
     -(ModelUnit *) modl{

        if(!modl){
            modl = [[ModelUnit alloc] init];
        }
        return modl;
    }

    - (IBAction)nickEntered:(UITextField *)sender{

        [[self modl] setName:[sender text]];

        ViewController *vew = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

        [self presentViewController:vew animated:NO completion:Nil];


    }
```

And here is how i try to receive and display it in the last viewcontroller:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    introViewController *pnt = [[introViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [display setText:[[pnt modl] getName]];
 }
```

But it always prints it as null when i NSlog it to the console. I know it's a very novice question but i'm completely stuck. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because each of your `UIViewController` instances are referencing different instances of your model class (actually, a non-instance in the second case).

Make an `@property` in your "last" view controller (class name of "ViewController" it would seem), something like:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Model *model;
```

Then, when pushing your second view controller, set its `model` property, like this:

```
ViewController *vew = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
vew.model = self.modl;
[self presentViewController:few animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

That way, you're passing around the same instance of your `Model` class. The way you're doing it, you're trying to access a property that was never initialized, which is why you're getting `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not new to OOP, you should quite easily see the mistake you're making.  You're trying to retrieve a value out of an object you just initialized.

Where you need to pass the data is in the first object as you initialized the second object.

Between this line:

```
ViewController *vew = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

And this line:

```
[self presentViewController:vew animated:NO completion:Nil];
```

You're still in the first object and you hold a reference to the second object.  Give the `ViewController` class (a better name and) a `NSString` property to hold the data the `getName` method returns.  And then set that property between the two lines I posted.

Also, Objective-C doesn't name their getters with `get`.